# How to set maxMessageSize and maxTransactionSize in networkParameterOverrides block in deployNodes task?

Tags: gradle, corda

In my project's root build.gradle file, my deployNodes task looks like this:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }
    node {...}
    node {...}
    node {...}
    node {...}
    networkParameterOverrides{
        maxMessageSize=50000000
        maxTransactionSize=50000000
    }
}
```

And the error I am receiving while running the task is:

```
Could not set unknown property 'maxMessageSize' for object of type net.corda.plugins.NetworkParameterOverrides
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `networkParametersOverrides` section in the CordFormation plugin currently only supports package ownership parameters - see:

https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins/blob/master/cordformation/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/plugins/NetworkParameterOverrides.kt

And the original PR here: https://github.com/corda/corda-gradle-plugins/pull/190

It looks like the expected way to do this for development currently is by using the network bootstrapper: https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html#overriding-network-parameters-via-a-file

Comment: Yep, just saw that a few minutes ago. Thank you!